# Pinia issue with array inside object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

**My pinia store** inside a vue3 app, contains a `currentReservation` object with a `pricings` array property.

Each pricing got a property id and quantity, when i add a pricing is added inside the store & component, same for the quantity (can be increase or decrease).

But when i removed a pricing inside the store, inside `decreaseReservationPricing` if the quantity is 0. The store is updated, but inside my component the `storePricings` property is not removed. The quantity is update, but each object stay there.

> Note the fact that if i have added two pricing, when i removed one,
> inside the component i still got two (everything works fine inside the store).

**There is my component script:**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { Pricing, ReservationPricing } from '@/@types/base'

import formsUiBlock from '@/components/forms/ui/Block.vue'
import CardsPricingItem from '@/components/cards/PricingItem.vue'

import { useReservationStore } from '@/stores/modules/reservation'

defineOptions({
  name: 'FormsBooking',
})

defineProps<{ pricings: Pricing[] }>()

const reservationStore = useReservationStore()
const storePricings = computed(() => reservationStore.currentReservation.pricings as ReservationPricing[]).value

function getPricingQuantity(id: string) {
  return storePricings.find(storePricing => storePricing.id === id)?.quantity || 0
}

// Manage pricing reservation quantity
function increaseReservationPricing(id: string) {
  const currentPricing = storePricings.find(pricing => pricing.id === id)

  if (!currentPricing) return storePricings.push({ id, quantity: 1 })
  currentPricing.quantity += 1
}

function decreaseReservationPricing(id: string) {
  const currentPricing = storePricings.find(pricing => pricing.id === id)

  if (currentPricing && currentPricing.quantity > 0) currentPricing.quantity -= 1
  if (currentPricing?.quantity === 0) reservationStore.cleanPricings()
}
</script>
```

**My store:**

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

// import { postReservation } from '@/api/reservation'
import { ReservationStore } from '../@types/base'
import { ReservationPricing } from '@/@types/base'

const currentReservationInit = {
  clientId: '',
  locationId: '',
  offerId: '',
  day: null,
  hours: {
    opening_hours: null,
    closing_hours: null,
  },
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
  phoneNumber: '',
  information: '',
  pricings: [],
  amount: null,
}

export const useReservationStore = defineStore('reservation', {
  state: (): ReservationStore => ({ currentReservation: currentReservationInit }),
  actions: {
    async postReservation() {
      // need to be set
    },
    cleanPricings() {
      const pricings = this.currentReservation.pricings as ReservationPricing[]
      this.currentReservation.pricings = pricings.filter(pricing => pricing.quantity !== 0)
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a mistake to access `value` immediately, this prevents `storePricings` from reacting to `currentReservation.pricings` changes and defies the purpose of a computed.

It should be:

```
const storePricings = computed(() => 
  reservationStore.currentReservation.pricings as ReservationPricing[]
)
```

And used like:

```
unref(storePricings).find(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed the ```.value``` after the computed is the problem. Just to illustrate, the unref do a ternary and take .value or the value itself is not required.

I try it with storeToRefs, but this not works, it's only works when i used a computed, someone have a idea why?

Comment: unref(storePricings) is the same as `storePricings?.value`, the latter is obscure because there may be non-reactive objects with .value property. Can you post the exact code that fails?

Comment: Thanks for the response, i retry with storeToRefs.
If i replace only with this and use currentReservation inside the computed:
```const { currentReservation } = storeToRefs(reservationStore)```
It works.

But what i have understand inside the docs that the binding stay with storeToRefs and i do not need to use computed, i maybe missunderstand https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#Destructuring-from-a-Store

Comment: This way you can shorten it to `currentReservation.value.pricings`, but you couldn't destructure `pricings` without another step, `const { pricings } = toRefs(currentReservation.value)`, and this won't work correctly if store.currentReservation is reassigned. Also storePricings is readonly and prevents from accidentally changing `value`

Comment: Thanks for the response, indeed if i use ```currentReservation.value.pricings``` the array is updated.
But if i assign it ```const storePricingsWithRefs = currentReservation.value.pricings```this is updated like before only inside the object, the object is not remove from the array.

I have some trouble to understand who pinia works. I just try to understand, but for this problem i will stay with the computed who seems to solve the problem and be readable.

Comment: Not specific to Pinia or computeds in general, it's about not keeping a reference that may become invalid. When you reassign `currentReservation.pricings =`, `storePricingsWithRefs` refers to stale array, `storePricingsWithRefs !== currentReservation.value.pricings`. By accessing it via the whole path like reservationStore.currentReservation.pricings (within a computed or not) you always access up-to-date array.

Comment: Thanks, it's true that it seems normal, i'm just not used to it maybe (i use vuex before). It's just weird because the object inside the array keep up-to-date but not the array itself (when we remove a object), so i think "this is the good way".

Comment: Yes, it it. It's this kind of scenario, `let foo = { value: { bar: 1 }}; let getBar = () =>  foo.value.bar; let oldFooVal = foo.value; foo.value = { bar: 2 }`, where `oldFooVal != foo.value`, and `getBar() != oldFooVal.bar`. It wasn't that obvious in Vuex because it had mapState helper that handled this

Comment: Yes exactly it's that!
Like you say i think about it before, and i say too me that mapState create a computed everytime. It just wasn't obvious and seems redundant to have to do it every time, but it's better. Thanks a lot for the explanation :)